# SoapUI - Groovy - RegEx - Match empty or date

Tags: regex, groovy, soapui

I have the code below which works when there is nothing between the RawValue tags however I need to match the scenario when there is nothing between the RawValue tags or a date in the format 5/11/2015. I though .* would match anything but I think the / is causing issue. Any ideas

```
sw = sw.replaceAll(/\<QuestionType\>Date\<\/QuestionType\>\s+\<RawValue\>\.*\<\/RawValue\>/){
'<QuestionType>Date</QuestionType>         <RawValue>' + sdf.format(date) + '</RawValue>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're escaping the `.` character. By default `.` character in regex match *Any character*, however if you escape it `\.` it match exaclty the dot. See [java pattern regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

So change your regex to:

`/\<QuestionType\>Date\<\/QuestionType\>\s+\<RawValue\>.*\<\/RawValue\>/`.